# Session existing even after invalidating it

Tags: java, session, authentication

I have basic login-logout session management problem.
When i click login button, this function below gets triggered.After LDAP authentication, it moves to index.html where I display their name.

```
 function validate()
            {
                var pageTitle=$(document).attr('title');
                var un=document.getElementById('username').value;
                var pwd=document.getElementById('pass').value;
                $.ajax({
                    'url':'/analytics_1/validate',
                    'data':'userName='+un+'&password='+pwd,
                    'type':'GET',
                    'success':function(response)
                    {
                        if(response==1)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                'url':'/analytics_1/LogButton',
                                'type':'POST',
                                'data':'userName='+un+'&buttonId=VIKALPLoginButton&pageTitle='+pageTitle,
                                'success':function()
                                {
                                    window.open("index.html","_self");
                                }
                                });

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Invalid Credentials");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

I create the Session in LogButton.java after checking if it's new

```
if(session.isNew())
            {
                System.out.println("session is not set, lets create the name");
                associate=req.getParameter("userName");
                session.setAttribute("Associate",associate);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("session is already set, lets get the name");
                associate=(String)session.getAttribute("Associate");
            }
```

I get their name from the session I created after successful login

And I do some actions and logout,

```
$('#logout').on('click',function()
        {
            var pageTitle=$(document).attr('title');
            $.ajax({
                    'url':'/analytics_1/LogButton',
                    'data':'buttonId=VIKALPLogoutButton&pageTitle='+pageTitle,
                    'type':'POST',
                    'success':function()
                    {
                        window.open('Login.html',"_self");
                    },
                    'error':function(err)
                    {
                        alert("haha:"+err.response);
                    }
            });
        });
```

In LogButton.java, I check if button is VIKALPLogoutButton, if true, i proceed to invalidate the session and remove Attribute

```
if(button.equals("VIKALPLogoutButton"))
            {
                System.out.println("deleting the session cuz of logout");
                session.removeAttribute("Associate");
                session.invalidate();
                //System.out.println("what happens to the session? " +session.isNew());
            }
```

All these happen as per required. Now comes the security use case : What should happen if I go to index.html without logging in?

So I started checking if session is set or not when index.html loads,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
                'url':'/analytics_1/GetAssocId',
                'type':'POST',
                'success':function(response)
                {
                    if(response!="null")
                        {}
                    else
                    {
                        window.open("Login.html","_self");
                    }
                    $('#name').text(response);
                }
            });
.....
.....
}
```

GetAssocId.java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    HttpSession session=req.getSession();
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    out.print(session.getAttribute("Associate"));
}
```

This also works fine, i.e it redirects me to Login.html if the session isn't created.

Now the thing is, I cannot Login, even after providing valid credentials, somehow the "Associate" attribute is set to null,

Below is the System.out.println output that I get in cmd
[image]

Above white line: Login,Logout action (notice the session invalidate output that I've given)

Below white line: Go directly to index.html, it redirects to Login.html, and you Login with your valid credentials,

Now this is my problem, It invalidates the session, yet still it says session is already existing . Even more confusing is, session is existing, but the value is null.

How do I overcome this problem? Please help

P.S:Other than the snippets I've provided for LogButton.java are not significant for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 HttpSession session=req.getSession();
```

If you look at the docs of [`getSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-) method

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>   If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.

You are calling `req.getSession()` method which gives you a new session. Probably to get the existing session you need to use

```
HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
```

As you already invalidate the session, this gives you session as `null` .

Your other question

> Now this is my problem, It invalidates the session, yet still it says session is already existing . Even more confusing is, session is existing, but the value is null.

It's because you created a new session, there are no attributes in it and that is the reason you getting `null`

Comment: Thank you suresh! in addition to your answer, it seems I was doing the wrong type of variable-check in index.html, instead of giving the null in 'error' of ajax, I was checking that up like a string in 'success' !
Cheers